# Little "holes" on carbon rims' profile: what are they used for?

Tags: tire, wheels, carbon

I have mounted a new set of carbon rims on my bike. To be precise, it's a pair of Mavic Cosmic SL. And I've noticed that they have some little "holes" along the profile.

What are they used for? Since I'm planning to attach the stickers on them, I like to know if I can cover these holes with them, or I have to adjust the stickers in a way to let these holes free.

Sorry if it is a silly question, and thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I'd leave the stickers off entirely. I like the cleaner appearance. but mounting three stickers with three holes shouldn't be hard -- put each sticker between two holes?

Comment: @arne, I agree with you: in theory it is not that hard, but the fact is that those tyres already have little Mavic stickers on them (they are not visible in that portion in the picture), and I already have to take them into account. So, a lot of little details that overlap with the future stickers, and I need to cover the lowest amount of them :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are drain holes to let water out.

Light bicycle go into slightly more detail on their webpage: https://www.lightbicycle.com/newsletter/Holes-On-Your-Carbon-Fiber-Rims.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've noticed that my rims have three of them for each side. So, basically, I imagine it is better to not cover them with stickers, but it won't be a big thing if one out of three would be covered (it's a bit difficult to place threes stickers by each side - as Cosmic standard - by leaving all of them uncovered).

Comment: @Andrea just poke a little hole through the sticker in the relevant spot after installing it.

Comment: Thank you, @MaplePanda: I will proceed like that.

Comment: Minor detail: I don’t think these drain holes are common, but these rims have a non-structural carbon fairing with entry holes for the spokes. So, the drain holes do actually help here. This is a relatively rare type of rim.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I would beg to differ as to your claim that these holes are not common.  My Roval's have them and I have seen them in other brands as well.  They may not be universal, but I believe they are more common than you imply.  I could be mistaken however...

Comment: @TedHohl fair enough, perhaps I should rephrase to they aren’t universal on structural carbon rims (which is just about all carbon rims)